# Report Viewer Not Showing any RDLC Report

Tags: c#, wpf, rdlc

I am creating Dataset and Datatable Dynamically to bind to Report1.rdlc. Report Viewer not showing anything .

```
        DataSet d = new DataSet();
        d.DataSetName = "DataSet1";
        d.GetXmlSchema();
        d.WriteXmlSchema(@"path + "/ds.xsd");
        d.WriteXml(@"path + "/ds.xml");

        DataTable Table1 = new DataTable();
        Table1.TableName = "TblPackage";

        Table1.Columns.Add("ID");
        Table1.Columns.Add("Name");
        Table1.Columns.Add("Description");
        Table1.Columns.Add("AddedBy");
        Table1.Columns.Add("AddedDate");
        Table1.Columns.Add("UpdatedBy");
        Table1.Columns.Add("UpdatedDate");

        d.Tables.Add(Table1);
        d.BeginInit();
        this.reportViewer.Reset();
        _reportDataSource.Name = "TblPackage";
        _reportDataSource.Value = EcadPackageList;
        this.reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        this.reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(_reportDataSource);
        this.reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"C:\ALF 4.0\CodeBase\ALF\Report\Report1.rdlc";
        d.EndInit();
        this.reportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Comment: any error you get ?

Comment: no error in report reportviewer..

Comment: it just shows blank report viewer